# Quick conversion of pcl::PointCloud<PointXYZ> to std::vector<cv::Point3f> using no iteration

Tags: c++, arrays, type-conversion

I'm looking for a quick way to convert a PCL point cloud of type `pcl::PointCloud<PointXYZ>` to `std::vector<cv::Point3f>`.

The problem is that `pcl::PointXYZ` consists of 4 floats (x, y, z, padding) while `cv::Point3f` only has 3 floats (x, y, z). If they were both just 3 floats I could do a simple pointer cast of the data buffer.

So, the underlying question basically is: how to convert an array of structs with 4 floats into an array of structs with 3 floats without using iteration (i.e. for loops)?

Comment: You can't. But if you don't like loops in you code you can use for example `std::transform`. But maybe what you really need is the proper iterator?

Answer (score 0):

If you have some point cloud `pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZ> cloud` and you want to create a vector of points containing the OpenCV type `cv::Point3f` just use range-based for loop like that:

```
std::vector<cv::Point3f> points;

for (const auto& point : cloud) {
    points.push_back(cv::Point3f(point.x, point.y, point.z));
}
```